# DSE cassandra driver for java returning only partial results in async mode

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-driver

I'm getting only partial set of rows when fetching from cassandra using dse cassandra driver 3.1.4 for java. 
Also This query is working fine with the earlier version of driver we were using.
The earlier version was 2.1.9

Table structure is like this

```
Key     column1 value
CM~020  000001000  20
CM~010  000001000  10
```

When I query for multiple rows using async call, I get only one row most of the time. Sometimes while debugging I get another row as well.

The behaviour is random but I always get either 2nd row or both. I never get the first row only, so I think this has some role to play here as well.

```
for (Object partitionKey : partitionKeys) {
        paramArray[0] = partitionKey;
        futures.add(session.executeAsync(boundStatement.bind(paramArray)));
}
```

Is there a way to make sure I get all the rows every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious thing here is that you have race condition - I see that you're re-using the same array object to specify parameters, and from your source code it looks like that you're using the same `BoundStatement` instance, so you're overwriting request data...

I recommend instead modify your code to use `preparedStatement.bind(paramArray)` instead of `boundStatement.bind(paramArray)` -> it will create new `BoundStatement` instance instead.

P.S. If it did work before, then this was just coincidence...

Comment: also will want to use a different paramArray, not reuse same one modifying between requests

Comment: reuse could be ok - I checked that when `bind` is called, then it uses this data only during the call.